# Spark Streaming DStream element vs RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using Spark's Streaming API, I just wanted to get a better understanding for how to best design the code.

I'm currently using Kafka Consumer (in pyspark) from pyspark.streaming.kafka.createDirectStream

According to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

> Spark Streaming provides a high-level abstraction called discretized
>   stream or DStream, which represents a continuous stream of data.
>   DStreams can be created either from input data streams from sources
>   such as Kafka, Flume, and Kinesis, or by applying high-level
>   operations on other DStreams. Internally, a DStream is represented as
>   a sequence of RDDs.

Essentially, I want to apply a set of functions to each of the elements in the DStream. Currently, I'm using the "map" function for pyspark.streaming.DStream. According to documentation, my approach seems correct. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html#pyspark.streaming.DStream

> map(f, preservesPartitioning=False) Return a new DStream by applying a
>   function to each element of DStream.

Should I be using map, or would the right approach be to apply functions/transformations to the RDDs (Since DStream uses RDD)??

> foreachRDD(func) Apply a function to each RDD in this DStream.

More Docs:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.streaming.html

Answer (score 1):

`DirectStream.map` is a correct choice here. Following `map`:

```
stream.map(f)
```

is equivalent to:

```
stream.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.map(f))
```

`DirectStream.foreachRDD` from the other hand is an output action and creates an output `DStream`. Function you use with `foreachRDD` is not expected to return anything, same as the method itself. It is obvious when take a look at the Scala signature:

```
def foreachRDD(foreachFunc: RDD[T] => Unit): Unit
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I did some research, and studied the documentation. Essentially, I want to do all the transformations/massaging aspects through the mapping/transform/filter functions. To insert into the database (i.e. some "side functions"), I will utilize the .foreachRDD

Comment: This is not a very useful approach beyond very simple applications. Any transformation which is applied inside `foreachRDD` is lost when you exit its closure. So it means that you can only apply "linear` workflows.

Comment: What is not an useful approach beyond simple applications? Would you further elaborate on that, not sure what you meant. 

As for foreachRDD, my intention was just using that to insert data into a database.